# Rails restarting form success page adds another record to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

i stumbled upon this problem and can't seem to figure out how to solve it. I have from which created record in database if valid, than it redirects to another page which instance and shows thank you popup. But if i restart that page to which redirect went i see that there is another record added to database and thank you popup shows its self again. How could i avoid this?

Form is simple form without any ajaxes just submit, validates, if ok saves and redirects, if error brings back to form with errors.

here is the form:

```
  = form_for @vacancy_application, url: {action: "create"}, html: {multipart: true, class: "block valid"} do |f|
    %fieldset
      %span.field_error_message= error_message_for(@vacancy_application, :cv)
      %label{for: "vacancy_application_cv"}= t("vacancy.form.cv")
      = f.file_field :cv
      = f.hidden_field :retained_cv
    %fieldset
      %label{for: "vacancy_application_mv"}= t("vacancy.form.mv")
      = f.file_field :mv
      = f.hidden_field :retained_mv
    %footer
      = f.submit
```

And here is the controller:

```
def create
    @vacancy = Vacancy.where(active: true).last
    @vacancy_application = VacancyApplication.new(app_params)
    @success_popup = true

    respond_to do |format|
      if @vacancy_application.save
        format.html { render action: "index"  }
        format.json { render json: @success_popup, status: :successfully_sent }
        set_side_menu_elements
      else
        format.html { render action: "vacancy_application" }
        format.json { render json: @vacancy_application.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
    end
  end
```

How and what should i do to avoid this kind of behaviour? Thank you :)

Comment: It's because you're not actually redirecting looking at that code.  So refreshing sends all the parameters to create again

Comment: how should i change the code so i reirect? controller: "vacancy, action: "index" ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a `render` after create you're effectively looking at the page created by submitting the form request.  If you reload, you will submit the form again (the browser may warn you about this).

If you did a `redirect` after create, you're starting from scratch on the page you redirect to, in a new controller action.  If you refresh that page, it's like being redirected to it again - it won't do the stuff that happened before the redirect, as that's now in a previous request (or action if you like).

So, if you redirect to the index, instead of render the index, that will stop the refresh-resubmit problem.  However, because of the redirect you won't have access to the instance variables you created (@success_popup, etc), because you're starting from scratch in the new action.

If that's a problem then you could use a `flash` instead perhaps?

Comment: Okey what i did was format.html { redirect_to controller: "vacancies", action: "index" , success_popup: true}

Comment: And then look for `params[:success_popup]` in the index action i assume?